# Android studio Setup Wizard next button frozen

Tags: android, android-studio

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and installing Android studio but facing this unknown issue

[image]

Finish and Next button are frozen.
Why?

Comment: Maybe if you scroll down the terms there is a checkbox to check?

Comment: Or accept the `android-sdk-arm-dbt` license too.

Answer (score 0):

Those marked * , you have to select them separately after selecting all three , the finish button gets highlighted. Hope that works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).